# Lua: Getting passed args when called function

Tags: lua

I want to get the parameters that passed to a specific function.

for example:

```
load("return 2+1")()
```

wanted output:

```
return 2+1
```

I have no idea after reading debug library :(

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you want, override the load function prior to calling it:

```lua
local global_load = load
local function load (...)
    print (...) -- or use whatever debug tool to see the arguments.
    return global_load (...)
end
```

You can redefine any function this way:

```lua
local function verbose (func)
    return function (...)
        print (...) -- or use whatever debug tool to see the arguments.
        return func (...)
    end
end

local load = verbose (load)

print (load 'return 2 + 1' ())
```